# Why was this post deleted when there are MANY just like it that weren't?

Tags: discussion, scope, deleted-questions, moderation

This post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973327/and-another-how-to-get-a-3d-earth-with-countries-as-border-chapes-into-my-ne) was deleted by moderators:

Title: **And another: How to get a 3D Earth, with countries as border chapes, into my .NET application? [closed]**

This is silly. In the message I added at the top lots of examples of similar questions (some even on the same exact topic!) that are alive & well out there. So check this one out (located [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588965/simple-3d-earth-globe-library-implementation))... It asks the same exact question I did!!!:

> Simple 3D Earth Globe library/implementation up vote 0 down vote
>   favorite
>
> I've been trying to find a library for rendering a simple 3D Earth
>   Globe in C#, but what I find is always too advanced, and mostly online
>   (ie: Integrate with Google Earth).
>
> What I'm looking for in such a library is:
>
> ```
> Offline (all data locally). The globe just needs to display a texture of earth, not have dynamic information of coast-lines, roads,
> ```
>
> cities etc.
>       Can rotate the globe with the mouse.
>       Can zoom in on the globe (just increasing size of texture, no need to display more detailed information when zooming in).
>       Has an API to paint overlay on the globe (preferably using real Geo-coordinates).
>       Has an API to catch clicks on the globe (preferably using real Geo-coordinates).
>
> From what I could find GMaps.NET comes closest, but it's still way to
>   advanced for what I really need. Is there a simple 3D Earth Globe
>   library out there?

The complaint:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem
>   and what has been done so far to solve it." – Will, Gayot Fow,
>   Plutonix, Clemens, brasofilo

The meat of the message:

> Moderators: I can't ask this question, yet ones JUST LIKE IT are all
>   over this site, doing fine? Just one example: WinForms / .Net
>   interactive world map - how?
>
> And ANOTHER: Simple 3D Earth Globe library/implementation
>
> Experts,
>
> I'd like to ask the same question asked 3 years ago here.
>
> The parameters are really simple:
>
> -Using Visual Studio 2012, VB.NET, and can convert C# easily enough... -Stand-alone application, phones home via W/S for updates. Think lots of clients, one server. -Application data in local SQL Server 2012.
>   -No winforms, all WPF for interfaces (so far).
>
> Needs are also very simple:
>
> -An interface (probably WPF, due to wanting fewest moving parts/languages). -Interface has earth on it, but just country
>   outlines. -Earth can be mouse rotated, rotate on it's own (spin), etc.
>   -Data is per country, and is represented by (at first) colors filling the country within it's borders. Think a color ramp, not the one in
>   your class schoolroom that had colors to delineate borders.
>   -Cost/performance: Really want the world map to be a static, one time dataset, and how each is shaded being the way the data is represented.
>   I see stuff like this, and I drool!
>
> That's it!

The moderators here at SO are trying to do a good job, but they are missing the spirit of the forums, looking at precedent, and standing on the letter of the rules with one user, and not another.

Can we just get back to asking the questions?

---

You may, of course, be right. So if you insist, then here are your choices:

**1. Undelete my post.**

**2. Delete ALL the other posts that are breaking the same rules that you say mine are, and cause mine to be deleted.**

Simple.

---

Comment: Thanks for drawing our attention to other off-topic posts. I've cast my votes to close them. Remember: we are all human and community moderation is not flawless.

Comment: *"when there are MANY just like it that weren't?"* ... that more often than not simply means we haven't gotten to those (yet).

Comment: Posts to help close, downvote, and delete: `(1)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651206/winforms-net-interactive-world-map-how, `(2)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386734/which-3d-graphics-toolkit-should-i-use-to-build-a-simple-3d-globe-with-country-o, `(3)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588965/simple-3d-earth-globe-library-implementation

Comment: SE isn't a collection of 'forums'.

Comment: Why did you ask a question that already exists exactly as you asked it?

Comment: @Daedalus, then they are a collection of forums with gamification implemented for (virtually) self-moderated forums. Less headache for the original owner.

Comment: @BradWerth, there are many reasons why this can happen. In the case above, the original question remained unanswered. Also, it is really hard to ask an identical question. There are always subtle differences. When I look at the suggestion thingie when authoring, I go to these other posts, and I'll still post if the answers weren't there, didn't apply, or were even fragments of the solution. Besides, that wasn't the case here. If you look, the complaints from users (as mods) was they I was not allowed to ask for a SW recommendation-even though countless posts do. It wasn't about dupes.

Comment: So you can all rest: I give up. No matter what I do, it is wrong. I've said my peace, and what needs to be addressed to improve the system, so I'll not waste any more of your time with it. I get negative votes no matter what I do, so I just have nto not make votes/points/gamification a priority. Sorry to have bothered you all.

Comment: @PatTrainor Wrong, they aren't any kind of forums.  This is a Q&A site.  Insistence that SE community is a collection 'forums' doesn't make it so.  Nor are you correct at treating the collection of rep as some sort of game.  If you want positive votes, stop treating this like a game, and stop with the 'this is a forum' attitude.  Try to be more open to opposing views, and attempts at help.  Lastly, I wouldn't try making demands like you did at the bottom of this question.

Comment: Forum, noun, "a place, meeting, or medium where ideas and views on a particular issue can be exchanged." - I hate to say it, but Stack Exchange is indeed a collection of forums.

Comment: @corsiKa Put your dictionary away. We are, of course, talking about **Internet forums** a.k.a. message boards where people hold informal and open discussion about a particular topic. SE is a network of Q&A sites, not discussion sites (meta and chat notwithstanding).

Comment: @PLEASEDELETEME: Perhaps stop and consider why your posts are getting downvoted/deleted. Your attitude here is a pretty good indication. Don't take what happens on StackOverflow so seriously. No one is out to get you. People vote down/close for a multitude of reasons. I too have experienced random unexplainable downvotes. I once had an answer downvoted after it already had 17 upvotes. Explain that one. Just post quality content and be gracious and polite. Everything else will take care of itself.

Comment: @PLEASEDELETEME What you want is this, posted in GameDev SE for your answer: "I have a sphere with a texture of the world. I need to make the countries clickable and am deciding if I should manually place cones for collision detection or if a math approach is better. I'm trying to avoid math, and curious what tools are available for easily mapping physics triggers to mouse clicks".  - Take note of experience with similar in actual games, Unity3D, DirectX, OpenGL, a basic understanding will be needed of one of them. Your Q is a common Game Prog thing

Answer (score 29):

No it wasn't deleted by moderators, it was deleted by the automatic clean up process:

> deleted by Community♦ Jun 18 at 3:02

It was closed by 5 regular users (no moderators involved here at all), and as a negatively scoring post with no answers it was eligible for clean up.

As for any other questions you find that don't fit the site, please just **flag** them for closure with the appropriate reason. They'll get seen (eventually) and closed. People will close (and even delete) questions when they see them, but we don't expect people to go looking for them.

The other thing to bear in mind is that in the early days of the site such questions were tolerated, so seeing such a question from 2010 shouldn't be taken as justification for posting a similar one now.

Comment: Is perhaps the message misleading? Something suggesting clean up, instead of "reasons of moderation". But perhaps it wouldn't make a difference, in this case the predisposition was not good.